# Recommended way of returning pointer from C++  function?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a pointer that is passed to a series of functions, where one function returns an address and assigns that address to the pointer.  After seeking some help on Stackoverflow, the `collect_file_path` method has a parameter of type `QStringList**`.  Although I understand what is going on I have not come across this notation in any of the text books I own, plus, it looks ugly.

I would like some advice/feedback on how other programmers would implement what I have done in the code below.  Would you use `QStringList**`, or some other method?

I hope what I'm asking makes sense. My current code is:

```
void ThreadWorker::run()
{
  QStringList* file_list;
  collect_file_paths(&file_list);
}

void ThreadWorker::collect_file_paths(QStringList** file_list)
{
  DirectorySearch ds;
  *file_list = ds.get_file_names(_strPath);
}

QStringList* DirectorySearch::get_file_names(QString path)
{
  QStringList *file_names = new QStringList;
  traverse(path, file_names);
  return file_names;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I would use `boost::shared_ptr` in first place

Comment: @rmflow: For the job of returning managed dynamically-allocated resources, I would use `auto_ptr` (`unique_ptr` where available), for the reason that it can be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr` if that's what the caller wants, or they can get the raw pointer out with `release()` if they have some other smart ptr that they prefer to `boost::shared_ptr`. For example, they might prefer `std::shared_ptr` where available, or some other smart pointer that I've never heard of. If you return `shared_ptr<QStringList>` they would then end up needing a `their_ptr<shared_ptr<QStringList> >`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass by pointer reference also, which is more C++ style:

```
void ThreadWorker::collect_file_paths(QStringList*& file_list) <-- see *&
{
}
```

You don't have to pass the address of `file_list` now:

```
collect_file_paths(file_list);  // simply pass it
```

But instead of that, I would still recommend following approach (which is simpler):

```
void ThreadWorker::run()
{
  QStringList* file_list = collect_file_paths();
}

QStringList* ThreadWorker::collect_file_paths()
{
  DirectorySearch ds;  //<---- ds uninitialized
  return ds.get_file_names(_strPath);  // for static function use ClassName::method() style
}
```

Comment: What do you mean uninitialized?  ds is just an instance of the DirectorySearch class.

Comment: @johnnyturbo3, since `ds` is not modified anywhere till the `return`, I suspect that in calling `get_file_names` there is no contribution of the `DirectorySearch` object. So to make the design proper you should declare `get_file_names` as `static` method inside the `class`. However, this is just a guess; you better know the design.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with returning a bare pointer is that it's quite easy to end up leaking the memory for the object. This might happen for example if anything in your function throws; but it can also happen on the caller's side, before they have received the pointer (e.g. if it is used as an argument to a function, and the evaluation of another argument throws).

For these reasons, it's best to wrap pointers in a smart pointer like `std::auto_ptr` (`unique_ptr` in the upcoming C++ standard) or `boost::shared_ptr` (also available as `std::shared_ptr`, soon in a standard library near you). These wrappers will safely take care of deleting the wrapped pointer when the time comes to do so.

However, in this specific case you can manage without using a `QStringList**` by passing the `QStringList*` as a reference.

Comment: that's not a problem with pointers, that's a problem with programmers!

Comment: @James: Well, I think it's fair to say that modern C++ style makes it practically impossible to write exception-safe code in the presence of bare pointers. Of course this can be solved by writing more code for  smart pointers, but I would certainly describe the whole affair as very difficult to get right even for experienced programmers.

Comment: Returning `shared_ptr` is antisocial, since it prevents the caller from using any other smart pointer type to manage the memory (the semantics of shared_ptr being that for all you know, the function that returned it has retained its own reference. There's no clean way to release the pointer from the shared_ptr). Returning single-owner smart pointers is fine, and IMO returning a raw pointer is fine provided that it's obvious the function allocates resources, and hence obvious to the caller those resources need to be stuffed directly into some resource manager of their own choosing.

Comment: Oh, and note that "prevents the caller using any other smart pointer type" means in particular that `boost::shared_ptr` and the new `std::shared_ptr` don't mix, despite being pretty much identical. So if you think you might ever migrate from one to the other, and your APIs enforce one or the other, AFAIK you're looking at a Great Big Simultaneous Change Everywhere. Not sure whether or not `namespace boost { using std::shared_ptr; }` solves this, maybe it does.

Answer (score 2):

Just return by value. The compiler can RVO, NRVO and you can swaptimize.

Answer (score 2):

You can return by value, since unnecessary copies will be optimized away.
This is a clear, exception safe and my recommended way.

```
void ThreadWorker::run()
{
  QStringList file_list = collect_file_paths();
}

QStringList ThreadWorker::collect_file_paths()
{
  DirectorySearch ds;
  return ds.get_file_names(strPath_);  // you should not use leading underscore in c++
}

QStringList DirectorySearch::get_file_names(QString path)
{
  QStringList file_names;
  traverse(path, &file_names);
  return file_names;
}
```

http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Btw. I think Qt Containers have copy on write optimizations, so the copy will be cheap even without compiler optimizations.

If you don't trust in (very common) compiler optimizations like RVO (comment by heishe) and you do not use copy-on-write objects like the QStringList you should create the instance in the run() method and pass a reference to the other functions. This is not as clear as my recommended technique but it is still exception safe (at least the basic guarantee).

```
void ThreadWorker::run()
{
  QStringList file_list;
  collect_file_paths(file_list);
}

void ThreadWorker::collect_file_paths(QStringList& file_list)
{
  DirectorySearch ds;
  ds.get_file_names(strPath_, file_list);  
}

void DirectorySearch::get_file_names(QString path, QStringList& file_list)
{
  traverse(path, &file_list);
}
```

A 3rd solution is to return a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<QStringList>`. But I cannot see any reason for an additional dynamic allocation in this example.

Comment: I always assumed that pass by reference was much faster than pass by value.

Comment: They are, and that's why I "-1"'d his answer. He's principally right in what he says, that compilers can optimize away here, but relying on compiler optimization with trivial problems like this is not a good idea at all. There will be more than enough cases where compilers can't optimize for whatever reason, and there reference passing will be faster.

Comment: @heishe: on the other hand, solving this "trivial" problem without relying on basic compiler optimisations has the extra cost of a memory allocation and (in the implementation presented in the question) a potential memory leak if `traverse` throws, as well as placing a burden on the calling code to correctly delete the returned pointer.

Comment: @heishe If you want to give the strong guarantee, the problem is not as trivial as you might think. If you pass by reference and change the state of this object it's not clear for the caller what to do with this object in case of exceptions.

Comment: Why should I not use a leading underscore for variable name?  I've been using them for class/instance variables.

Comment: @johnnyturbo3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: @johnnyturbo3: you can use a leading underscore for class member names if you really want to, as long as the second character isn't upper case, and you never use two consecutive underscores. However, you may find it easier to avoid them, rather than having to explain the rules governing reserved identifiers to people who think you're breaking them.

Answer (score 0):

It might look ugly but it's not that uncommon in some APIs to pass a double pointer.

In your case it seems unnecessary. Why does collect_file_paths not just return a pointer too?

Answer (score 0):

If you have allocated the memory with new-operator, you can just return the pointer. Also, remember to use delete to the allocated memory. Good place for this would normally be in the destructor method (not in this case, since you only use the memory in the run-method).

```
void ThreadWorker::run()
{
  QStringList* file_list;
  file_list = ds.get_file_names(_strPath);

  //here we do something with file_list
  //...

  //Free the memory. You have to do this if the object pointed by file_list is not
  //used anywhere else.
  delete file_list;
}

QStringList* DirectorySearch::get_file_names(QString path)
{
  QStringList *file_names = new QStringList;
  traverse(path, file_names);
  return file_names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user has access to the header but not to the implementation, he/she hasn't got any idea how to handle the pointer. If your function is a source (aka allocate the pointer with new) you should return an auto_ptr. auto_ptr are: standard, never throws and specifically design to do this job.

You may have a look at this http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm